# c++ mysql stored preocedure multiple out parameter error

Tags: c++, mysql

I use Freebsd 8.0 amd64,mysql-client-5.1.61, mysql-connector-c++-1.1.0, mysql-server-5.1.61 and gcc 4.2.1  Whay this is working

```
stmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE p(OUT retval VARCHAR(50)) BEGIN SELECT \"Ulf joined MySQL more than 5 years ago\" INTO retval; END;");

 pstmt.reset(con->prepareStatement("CALL p(@output)"));
 pstmt->execute();

 pstmt.reset(con->prepareStatement("SELECT @output AS _answer"));
 res.reset(pstmt->executeQuery());
 while (res->next())
     cout << "\t... _answer: " << res->getString("_answer") << endl;
```

and this not

```
stmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE p(OUT retval VARCHAR(50),OUT retval1 VARCHAR(50)) BEGIN SELECT \"Ulf joined MySQL more than 5 years ago\" INTO retval;SELECT \"Ulf joined MySQL more than 5 years ago\" INTO retval1;  END;");
pstmt.reset(con->prepareStatement("CALL p(@out1,@out2)"));
pstmt->execute();

pstmt.reset(con->prepareStatement("SELECT @out1 AS vOut,@out2 as vOut2"));
res.reset(pstmt->executeQuery());
while (res->next())
   cout << res->getString("vOut1") << res->getString("vOut2") << endl;
```

and return `ERR: MySQLPreparedResultSet::getString: invalid 'columnIndex' (MySQL error code: 0, SQLState:  )`
What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you copied your code verbatim, I think the problem is caused by a simple typo. In this line:

```
pstmt.reset(con->prepareStatement("SELECT @out1 AS vOut,@out2 as vOut2"));
```

The column names of your parameters are `vOut` and `vOut2`. But in the latter line:

```
cout << res->getString("vOut1") << res->getString("vOut2") << endl;
```

You refer them as `vOut1` and `vOut2`. There is no column with the name `vOut1`, because you named it `vOut`, hence the invalid column index error.